# Recovering from `panic!` in another thread

Tags: rust

I know that in Rust there is no try/catch, and you can't throw a rolling save from the thread that is currently panicking.

I know you ***should not*** create and handle errors like this. This is just for example's sake.

However, I am wondering what the best way to recover from a panic is. This is what I have now:

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let h = thread::spawn(|| {
        thread::sleep_ms(1000);
        panic!("boom");
    });

    let r = h.join();
    match r {
        Ok(r) => println!("All is well! {:?}", r),
        Err(e) => println!("Got an error! {:?}", e)
    }

    println!("Exiting main!");
}
```

Is there a better way to handle errors from other threads? Is there a way to capture the message of the panic? This seems to only tell me that the error is of type `Any`. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Putting aside "you should be using `Result` where possible," yes, this is basically how you catch a panic in Rust.  Keep in mind that "recover" is perhaps not the best way of phrasing this in Rust.  You don't really recover from panics in Rust, you *isolate* them, then *detect* them.  There is no `On Error Resume Next` :P.

That said, there are two things to add to your example.  First is how to get at the panic message.  The key observation is that `Any`, in order to be used, must be *explicitly* downcast to the exact, concrete type it contains.  In this case, since the panic message is a `&'static str`, you need to downcast to that.

The second thing is that there is a new API in nightly called `catch_panic` that lets you isolate a panic *without* having to start a thread.  That said, it comes with the same restrictions as spawning a new thread: you cannot pass a non-`'static` reference across the isolation boundary.  Note that this is an **unstable** addition; there are no guarantees about stability yet, and you'll need a nightly compiler to access it.

Here is an example which shows both of those.  You can also [run this on the Rust Playpen](http://is.gd/YFbMx9).

```rust
#![feature(catch_panic)]

use std::thread;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let h = thread::spawn(|| {
        thread::sleep_ms(500);
        panic!("boom");
    });

    let r = h.join();
    handle(r);

    let r = thread::catch_panic(|| {
        thread::sleep_ms(500);
        panic!(String::from("boom again!"));
    });

    handle(r);

    println!("Exiting main!");
}

fn handle(r: thread::Result<()>) {
    match r {
        Ok(r) => println!("All is well! {:?}", r),
        Err(e) => {
            if let Some(e) = e.downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
                println!("Got an error: {}", e);
            } else {
                println!("Got an unknown error: {:?}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! The bit about the error's format being `&'static str` was just what I needed. Thanks! I'm a little surprised that more things aren't stable now that Rust is 1.0, but also glad to have them not out in the wild before they're ready.

Comment: @jocull "1.0" doesn't mean "we're finished", it just means "ok, we're going to stop breaking everything every few days now."  If you expect the standard library to be "feature complete" because Rust is at 1.0, you're going to be rather bitterly disappointed. :)

Comment: @DK.: I would rather say "If you expect Rust to stop evolving now that it is 1.0, you're going to be pleasantly surprised" :)

Comment: Note that you probably also want to check for `e.downcast_ref::<String>()` if the panic can also be a non-static error message.