# in Rust how can I dump the result of a panic! returned by join() if it is not a &'static str?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a Rust program where I `spawn` a number of threads and store the `JoinHandle`s.  When I later `join` the threads that `panic!`ed, I'm not sure how to retrieve the message that was passed to `panic!`

[Recovering from `panic!` in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824258/recovering-from-panic-in-another-thread) covers a simple case, but when I applied it to my code it turns out it doesn't work, so I have updated my example:

If I run the following program

```
fn main() {
    let handle = std::thread::spawn(||panic!(format!("demo {}",1)));
    match handle.join() {
        Ok(_) => println!("OK"),
        Err(b) => println!("Err {:?}", b.downcast_ref::<&'static str>())
    }
}
```

([rust playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20handle%20%3D%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Aspawn(%7C%7Cpanic!(format!(%22demo%20%7B%7D%22%2C1)))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20handle.join()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(_)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22OK%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(b)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22Err%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20b.downcast_ref%3A%3A%3C%26%27static%20str%3E())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)
It prints `Err None` .  I want to access the `"demo"` message.

Comment: `format!()` returns a `String`, check for that instead.

Comment: panic!(format! is silly in this Minimal Working Example, but it is what is happening in my real code, and without it, I don't get the malfunction.

Comment: are you mixing your error panic type ? I bet your question doesn't contain your real problem

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, I was able to come up with a working solution ([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20handle%20%3D%20std%3A%3Athread%3A%3Aspawn(%7C%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20panic!(%22malfunction%20%7B%7D%22%2C%207)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20true%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(14)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(%22bacon%22.to_string())%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20match%20handle.join()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(msg)%20%3D%3E%20println!(%22OK%20%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20msg)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Err(b)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20msg%20%3D%20if%20let%20Some(msg)%20%3D%20b.downcast_ref%3A%3A%3C%26%27static%20str%3E()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msg.to_string()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20let%20Some(msg)%20%3D%20b.downcast_ref%3A%3A%3CString%3E()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20msg.clone()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20format!(%22%3F%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20b)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20msg)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)):

```
fn main() {
    let handle = std::thread::spawn(|| {
        panic!("malfunction {}", 7);
        if true {
            Err(14)
        } else {
            Ok("bacon".to_string())
        }
    });
    match handle.join() {
        Ok(msg) => println!("OK {:?}", msg),
        Err(b) => {
            let msg = if let Some(msg) = b.downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
                msg.to_string()
            } else if let Some(msg) = b.downcast_ref::<String>() {
                msg.clone()
            } else {
                format!("?{:?}", b)
            };
            println!("{}", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

which prints `malfunction 7` like I want.  While this toy example doesn't need all the branches, a more complex piece of code might have some `panic!`s that give `&'static str` and others that give `String`.

Comment: I was doing a code example for you too so here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=30e47955ce19aad9a8392d17a0fc13c7 probably better code in my link

Comment: also, please fix your question so cause here your question doesn't show this problem

Comment: This same approach will also work if you use `catch_unwind` within a thread.

Comment: Have you considered adding an answer rather than a comment, Stargateur?  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't show this problem".