# How do I self restart a thread in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust. I have the following code that spawns a thread and in that thread creates a camera thread using the nokhwa crate:

```
let mut handle_vec = vec![]; // JoinHandles will go in here
let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    let cameras = query(ApiBackend::Auto).unwrap();
    if cameras.len() > 0 {
        let requested: RequestedFormat =
            RequestedFormat::new::<RgbFormat>(RequestedFormatType::AbsoluteHighestFrameRate);
        // make the camera
        let mut camera = match CallbackCamera::new(CameraIndex::Index(0), requested, move |buf| {
            let val = percentile(&buf.decode_image::<LumaFormat>().unwrap(), 90);
            hists_clone.store(val, Ordering::Relaxed);
        }) {
            Ok(val) =>{
                val
            },
            Err(err) => {
                eprint!("{}", err);
                return;
            }
        };
        camera.open_stream().unwrap();
        loop {
        }
    }
});
handle_vec.push(handle); // save the handle so we can call join on it outside of the loop

loop {
    more code...
    //TODO HERE: check thread and restart if dead?
}
```

The goal is to create a callback camera object, and to do so while recovering in the event of err. If an err occurs, I'd like to simply restart the thread (so that I could try again). Sometimes the camera can disconnect causing an err, other times it may not be connected in the first place. How do I go about doing this? What would be a better approach?

EDIT:
Here is the commit with my implemented solution:
https://github.com/mmhobi7/matryx_generator/commit/8c02274a68f1b1d1a206841bad422e26b77189ea

Comment: `// save the handle so we can call join on it` -- did you try doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recovering from \`panic!\` in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824258/recovering-from-panic-in-another-thread)

Comment: put what you want to do in a function, and have the error call itself recursively before the return? This is probably an AWFUL idea. LOL.. that being said, if you want the error to ALWAYS restart, why not have a loop around the match, with a break inside the Ok? And maybe a timer delay inside the Err if time is needed to wait between attempts?

Comment: Are you concerned with `panic`s? Otherwise, why don't you simply loop inside of the thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is quite convoluted and uses many undefined functions, so let me reduce it down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for you:

```rust
use std::{
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::Duration,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Camera;

fn init_camera() -> Result<Camera, String> {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));

    let val: u8 = rand::random();
    if val < 50 {
        Ok(Camera)
    } else {
        Err("Camera failed to initialize!".to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut handle_vec = vec![]; // JoinHandles will go in here
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let camera = match init_camera() {
            Ok(val) => val,
            Err(err) => {
                eprintln!("{}", err);
                return;
            }
        };

        println!("We got a camera: {:?}", camera);

        // ... do something with camera
    });
    handle_vec.push(handle); // save the handle so we can call join on it outside of the loop

    loop {
        //more code...
        //TODO HERE: check thread and restart if dead?
    }
}
```

```
Camera failed to initialize!
... stuck forever inside of loop ...
```

Now theres multiple ways to solve this.

The easiest way would be to loop **inside** of the thread:

```rust
use std::{
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::Duration,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Camera;

fn init_camera() -> Result<Camera, String> {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));

    let val: u8 = rand::random();
    if val < 50 {
        Ok(Camera)
    } else {
        Err("Camera failed to initialize!".to_string())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut handle_vec = vec![]; // JoinHandles will go in here
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let camera = loop {
            match init_camera() {
                Ok(val) => break val,
                Err(err) => {
                    eprintln!("{}", err);
                    eprintln!("Retrying ...");
                }
            }
        };

        println!("We got a camera: {:?}", camera);

        // ... do something with camera
    });
    handle_vec.push(handle); // save the handle so we can call join on it outside of the loop

    for handle in handle_vec {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

```
Camera failed to initialize!
Retrying ...
Camera failed to initialize!
Retrying ...
We got a camera: Camera
```

If you have to be able to handle `panic()`s as well, you could double-spawn:

```rust
use std::{
    thread::{self, sleep},
    time::Duration,
};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Camera;

fn init_camera() -> Result<Camera, String> {
    sleep(Duration::from_millis(200));

    let val: u8 = rand::random();
    if val < 20 {
        Ok(Camera)
    } else if val < 100 {
        // Add chance that it panics
        panic!("Camera initialization panic!");
    } else {
        Err("Camera failed to initialize!".to_string())
    }
}

// Extracted into separate function because the nesting
// got too ridiculous
fn camera_thread() -> Result<(), String> {
    let camera = init_camera()?;
    println!("We got a camera: {:?}", camera);

    // ... do something with camera

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut handle_vec = vec![]; // JoinHandles will go in here
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| loop {
        match thread::spawn(camera_thread).join() {
            Ok(Ok(())) => break,
            Ok(Err(err)) => eprintln!("Thread failed: {:?}", err),
            Err(err) => eprintln!("Thread panicked: {:?}", err.downcast_ref::<&str>().unwrap()),
        }
        eprintln!("Retrying ...");
    });
    handle_vec.push(handle); // save the handle so we can call join on it outside of the loop

    for handle in handle_vec {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

```
Thread failed: "Camera failed to initialize!"
Retrying ...
Thread failed: "Camera failed to initialize!"
Retrying ...
Thread failed: "Camera failed to initialize!"
Retrying ...
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Camera initialization panic!', src/main.rs:17:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Thread panicked: "Camera initialization panic!"
Retrying ...
Thread failed: "Camera failed to initialize!"
Retrying ...
We got a camera: Camera
```

Of course there are many more ways, but those would be the ones that come to my mind.

But to answer your original question: no, there is no way for a thread to restart itself. You need to `loop` somewhere, either inside or outside of the thread.

Comment: Thanks! Gave me a ton to work with. I ended up with this: https://github.com/mmhobi7/matryx_generator/commit/8c02274a68f1b1d1a206841bad422e26b77189ea